# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::listen()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi there

I'm attempting to write a custom package for Laravel 4 that does some extra logging. According to the Laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs/errors), I can just create a listener and do what I need to in the Closure.

This is the register function inside the ServiceProvider

> use Log;

```php
public function register()
{
    Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context)
    {
        $vmlog = new Vmlog();
        $vmlog->log($level, $message, $context);
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

```php
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::listen()
```

This is the alias entry (which I haven't changed).

```php
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    ...
),
```

Where am I going wrong here, why can't I access the listen() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `register()` method in service providers can't guarantee that Laravel has fully booted when it is called. It should only be used to **register** IoC bindings and not much more. Never put any application logic in this method.

Instead move your code to the `boot()` method that is called once Laravel and your package are fully loaded.

```
public function boot() 
{
    Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context)
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: @SynackSA No problem we all make them ;-)